# Configure JSON Output depending on Spring Controller Method

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

For now I am using Jackson JSON Processor for returning JSON from an Object, but if there is a better way to do it, I am open for suggestions. The goal is to define which attributes will be included in the JSON response, depending on the method/url.

Example:

**Model**

```
class League {
  String name;
  List<Team> teams;
  ...
}

class Team {
  String name;
  String nation;
  int points;
  List<Player> players;
  ...
}

class Player {
  String name;
  Team team;
  ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LeagueController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/league",method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody
  League getLeague() {
    //return the teams shouldn't include the player list 
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/team/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody
  Team getTeamById(Long id) {
    //return team including the players but if possibe use the teamname inside the JSON
    //instead of the entire back reference (which producess an infinite loop.
  }
}
```

I looked in the Jackson annotations but it didn't get me any further or raised new problems.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a Jackson Custom Serializer.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the `JSON` customized annotation to ignore the fields , ignore the `null` , ignore `empty String` in your `java class` to `JSON` conversion as ,

```
@JsonIgnore
private KeyValueCollection userData;

private String participants = "";

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
private boolean garbageEligible;


@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) 
private String interactionType ;

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
private LinkedList<InteractionInfo> interactions;
```

I have used the `jackson 1.9`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try it the next days and come back to mark your answer or with additional questions.

Comment: welcome.Then please let me know what happened to you ?